# HTML player.swf playing x.flv files through popup div/window

Tags: html, flash

I've got the code:

```
< a class='vid' href='player.swf?url=folder/anotherfolder/file.flv&amp;volume=50' title=''><img src='wheremyimage.gif' width='200' height='150' alt='' /></a >
```

The problem is, the player isn't playing up my .flv file.

I suppose I am doing this incorrect, anyone out there that could help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
< a class='vid' href='player.swf?file=folder/anotherfolder/file.flv&amp;volume=50' title=''><img src='wheremyimage.gif' width='200' height='150' alt='' /></a >
```

Replace the "url" with "file", walla! Works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an embed tag. Something like:

```
<embed src = 'player.swf?url=folder/anotherfolder/file.flv&amp;volume=50' width="800" height="600" allowfullscreen="true" />
```